# How to avoid "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I type the command "pydoc tensorflow"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pydoc

The pydoc documentation command seems to be working perfectly for every module I have tried but the tensorflow module. It bugs me and I want to figure out why, and hopefully fix it. If I try the command `pydoc tensorflow.Dimension` things work as expected. I can `import tensorflow` and run tensorflow scripts without any problems.
I have seen the behavior in Anaconda and Ubuntu.

Feel free to ask me for more precisions or commands that I should use to get more detailed logs, if you don't observe the same behavior in your setup. There seems to be no verbose option for pydoc.

**Update 1:** I tried uninstalling and installing back tensorflow.

- First I uninstalled using pip because it seemed not to be installed with conda (I usually try and install packages using conda unless it does not work).
- I tried and installed it with conda, which led met to this error:

  ```
  anon~$ pydoc tensorflow
  problem in tensorflow - ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/anon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
      from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "/home/anon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
      _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "/home/anon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
      _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
    File "/home/anon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
      return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    File "/home/anon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
      return _load(spec)
  ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
  ```
- I therefore reinstalled it with pip and am back to the same point.

Comment: having trouble reproducing on ubuntu, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow?

Comment: I just edited my answer, following your advice (update 1).

Comment: Doesn't seems to be a pydoc issue which fails trying to import tensorflow. Does `import tensorflow` work fine in python? Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746576/tensorflow-with-cuda-importerror?

Comment: In my case, `import tensorflow` works beautifully, and I've been running tensorflow scripts without any problems. I still have the error on the documentation. My GPU is not NVIDIA so I don't intend to do GPU computation and don't see the point of following the tutorial there.

Comment: If you run it this way: `python -m pydoc tensorflow`, Ubuntu should give you a crash report in a form of a pop-up and a crash dump file available in `/var/crash` that is giving me `pydoc.py crashed with SIGSEGV in google::protobuf::python::message_meta::GetExtensionsByName()` which looks like a reportable issue.

Comment: Thank you, I don't get the pop up but I do have the crash report where it is expected. How do I get the pop up to send it with GUI ?
I tried to send it using the command `apport-cli`, it uploads the crash file and creates new `.upload` files, but it doesn't open a webpage as it says.

Comment: What's the next step of the process ?